# Move a Graphic object towards the cursor

Tags: java, graphics

I want to move a Graphics object towards the cursor when the user clicks a mousebutton, but I've got no idea how...

I have the position of the cursor and the Graphic object, but no clue on how i would change its X and Y to make "smooth" movement from the start location to the new point (where the user clicked)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General approach:

Have a model backing your graphics, and store the coordinate of each item in the model on the model.

1. Add a MouseListener and implement mousedown
2. In your listener grab the X,Y of the mouse event.
3. Decide how fast you want to move the object (constant speed? Constant time to reach cursor? Acclerating? Decelerating?)
4. Write an equation that describes the motion towards the cursor, preferably in terms of the distance remaining to be covered. For a very fast decelerating approach that could be distanceRemaining/5. (for example). Other motions require a bit of geometry/algebra, but that's your work :)
5. Create an object that encapsulates the above logic and has a flag to determine when the animation is complete.
6. Use a "animation" thread (or timing framework as mentioned above, I haven't used it) to perform 24 or more updates per second **to the X and Y coordinates of the model** based on the distance remaining in the X and Y direction and call repaint(). The thread should do this until the animation complete flag is true, and then stop calling repaint().
7. Java will then call the paint function for you at a rate that it knows it can handle (if you call too fast it will coalesce the extra calls for you and prevent you from locking up the program with a backlog of painting calls). Your paint function should simply draw the model based on it's current state whenever java chooses to call it.

It's important that you update x and y in the same thread, not independent threads. That sounds like a cool idea, but it fails because the thread scheduler will sometimes lag one thread and you can get 2 or 3 updates on one dimension without a corresponding update in the other, which will cause the object to move in a line that is not smooth. In most cases you should do all your updates to the model (for this and any other motion) in the same thread.

Note that your x & y in your model probably need to be float or double since you don't want to loose fractions of a pixel, especially if the motion is intended to be slow. Expressing the equation in terms of distance remaining avoids having to calculate the angle of the trajectory and using sine/cosine functions to perform the update. However, in some cases you may find it easier to calculate that angle and use sine/cosine instead, if you want a complex motion that isn't easily transformed to be expressed in terms of distance remaining. Do what makes your code clear, optimize later if needed.

24 updates per second is the standard frame rate for movie cameras and that number is a minimum that relates to [flicker fusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flicker_fusion_threshold#Display_frame_rate) of the human eye, if you update slower than that people will see the motion as jerky. For maximum smoothness you would want over 60 times a second, but that's probably only necessary for video games and creates a much bigger performance cost. Pick the minimum update rate that you find visually satisfactory.

It's also a good idea to have a flag on the update thread that turns it on and off when there's something to update so it isn't requesting repaint for no reason when there's nothing to animate. Be sure that the flag is marked with the volatile keyword since it will be updated by other threads. If you have multiple animations going on at one time, you might turn the thread on and off based on presence of animation objects in a list (removing them when they are complete)

Answer (score 0):

The Swing [timing framework](http://java.net/projects/timingframework/) can help you with much of the grunt work.